# Spree Commerce: local product images

Tags: paperclip, spree

Is it possible to set up SpreeCommerce so that it uses files in

```
public/
```

while in `development` environment while using S3 in `production` for product and taxon images?

Answer (score 0):

You can [save spree taxon icon image on S3](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1744).
I think you could use an if statement to check where Rails.env == 'development' and use or don't the S3 feature.

```
Spree::Taxon.class_eval do
  # Load user defined paperclip settings
  if Spree::Config[:use_s3]
    s3_creds = { :access_key_id => Spree::Config[:s3_access_key], :secret_access_key => Spree::Config[:s3_secret], :bucket => Spree::Config[:s3_bucket] }
    Spree::Taxon.attachment_definitions[:icon][:storage] = :s3
    Spree::Taxon.attachment_definitions[:icon][:s3_credentials] = s3_creds
    Spree::Taxon.attachment_definitions[:icon][:s3_headers] = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Spree::Config[:s3_headers])
    Spree::Taxon.attachment_definitions[:icon][:bucket] = Spree::Config[:s3_bucket]
  end
end
```